# Displaying tag for listing environment like math environments

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, listings, amsmath, tags

I'm using `listings` to better typeset code that was originally placed in an undesirable environment (`verbatims` inside `eqnarray` with negative space for each line) due to journal submission requirements.

However, one advantage to using a math environment like `equation` is you get either an automatic or manual tag on the right-hand side. I would like to reproduce that with `listings`, without the need for a caption.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}

% slightly nicer listings output
\lstset{%
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,%
  breakatwhitespace=true,%
  breaklines=false,%
  frame=none,%
  numberbychapter=false,%
  numbers=left,%
  numberstyle=\tiny,
}

\begin{document}

\textcolor{blue}{1st test: aligned verbatims in equation}
\begin{equation}
  \label{snip:1}
  \begin{aligned}
    &\verb!import numpy, psi4! \\
    &\verb!np_array = numpy.zeros((5, 5))! \\
    &\verb!psi4_matrix = psi4.core.Matrix.from_array(np_array)! \\
    &\verb!new_np_array = numpy.array(psi4_matrix)!
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\textcolor{blue}{2nd test: aligned verbatims in eqnarray}
\begin{eqnarray}
  \begin{aligned}
    &\verb!import numpy, psi4! \\
    &\verb!np_array = numpy.zeros((5, 5))! \\
    &\verb!psi4_matrix = psi4.core.Matrix.from_array(np_array)! \\
    &\verb!new_np_array = numpy.array(psi4_matrix)!
  \end{aligned}
  \label{snip:2}
\end{eqnarray}

\textcolor{blue}{3rd test: listing without caption}
\begin{lstlisting}[label=snip:3]
import numpy, psi4
np_array = numpy.zeros((5, 5))
psi4_matrix = psi4.core.Matrix.from_array(np_array)
new_np_array = numpy.array(psi4_matrix)
\end{lstlisting}

\textcolor{blue}{4th test: listing with caption}
\begin{lstlisting}[label=snip:4,caption=I am an unwanted caption.]
import numpy, psi4
np_array = numpy.zeros((5, 5))
psi4_matrix = psi4.core.Matrix.from_array(np_array)
new_np_array = numpy.array(psi4_matrix)
\end{lstlisting}

Using standard \verb!\ref{label}!:
\begin{itemize}
\item The first test is \ref{snip:1}.
\item The second test is \ref{snip:2}.
\item The third test is \ref{snip:3}.
\item The fourth test is \ref{snip:4}.
\end{itemize}

Using \verb!\autoref{label}! from \texttt{hyperref}:
\begin{itemize}
\item The first test is \autoref{snip:1}.
\item The second test is \autoref{snip:2}.
\item The third test is \autoref{snip:3}.
\item The fourth test is \autoref{snip:4}.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

with the output:

[image]
[image]

It looks like `listings` doesn't even bother with a counter for instances that don't have captions. How can I get the look and behavior of a math environment with `listings`, without the need for a caption?

Comment: eqnarray is an amsmath environment and the display is identical to if I had an equation, an align...it’s right in the image.

Comment: Depending on your desired output, maybe `numberedblock` might be of some use: https://ctan.org/pkg/numberedblock

Comment: @pentavalentcarbon -- `eqnarray` is an environment from basic latex.  it is *not* an `amsmath` environment, and in fact is deprecated for math use.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I was confused because the distinction is not clear to me. The eqnarray example is what I inherited, and has never been my choice of environment.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this could be an acceptable solution, but you can use a `tcolorbox` with no caption and your `listings` in it, put it in a `minipage` followed by an appropriate macro which prints the label.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\newtcblisting[auto counter]{mylist}[1][]{%
    title={},
    colback=white,
    colframe=white,
    listing only,
    enhanced,
    sharp corners,
    bottom=0pt,
    top=0pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
    leftrule=0pt,
    left=10pt,
    listing engine=listings,
    listing options = {
        basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,%
        breakatwhitespace=true,%
        breaklines=false,%
        frame=none,%
        numberbychapter=false,%
        numbers=left,%
        numberstyle=\tiny,
        numbersep=6pt,
    },
    #1 
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tcb@cnt@mylistautorefname}{Listing}
\newcommand{\printlabel}{\begin{minipage}{.05\linewidth}\raggedleft(\makeatletter\thetcb@cnt@mylist\makeatother)\end{minipage}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    You could use a \verb|tcolorbox| whithin a \verb|minipage| which is a little smaller than \verb|\linewidth| and write the (label) automatically side by side with an appropriate command. Please note that I didn't put spaces before the code.

    \noindent\begin{minipage}{.95\linewidth}
    \begin{mylist}[label=snip:4]
import numpy, psi4
np_array = numpy.zeros((5, 5))
psi4_matrix = psi4.core.Matrix.from_array(np_array)
new_np_array = numpy.array(psi4_matrix)
    \end{mylist}
    \end{minipage}
    \printlabel

    Using standard \verb!\ref{label}!:
    now is \ref{snip:4}.

    Using \verb!\autoref{label}! from \texttt{hyperref}:
    Now is \autoref{snip:4}.

\end{document}
```

[image]